# Возможно ли такое?

Tags: причастия

Возможно ли написать "умерены" в данной ситуации:
"Их аппетиты [были] умерен(н)ы [нами]" (то есть кто-то умерил кому-то аппетиты)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо смотреть **реальный текст**, где встречается это предложение.
Слово «умеренный» относится к группе **парных причастий** (обозначают признак по действию) **и прилагательных** (обозначают качественный признак). Важно отметить, что для таких пар **зависимое слово в Т.п.** (для причастий) или **наречие степени** (для прилагательных) используются **только  для проверки, но обязательными не являются.**

**(1) Прилагательное: *Их аппетиты умеренны.***

Например: *Теперь они ведут себя достаточно скромно. Их аппетиты **умеренны** и не превышают разумные пределы.*

**(2) Причастие: *Их аппетиты умерены.***

Например: *В настоящее время отношение к ним изменилось: их аппетиты **умерены** и регулируются в законодательном порядке.*

**Дополнительный материал:**

**(1) Орфографический словарь**

умеренный; кр. ф. прич. **-ен, -ена;** кр. ф. прил. (среднего уровня; скромный, без излишеств) **-ен, -енна**

**(2) Толковый словарь**

УМЕРЕННЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -рен, -ренна, -ренно. 1. Не слишком большой по размеру, количеству, силе и т.п., не выше среднего уровня, меры. *У. аппетит.* 2. в чем. Не предающийся излишествам, скромный в своих требованиях, желаниях, чувствах и т.п. (о ком-л.). *У. в еде человек. У. в желаниях.* 3. Не примыкающий к крайним политическим течениям. *У-ые взгляды.* 4. только полн. Геогр. Средний между жарким и холодным (о климате или месте с таким климатом). *У. климат.*

**(3) Примеры**

**Причастие**

*Как уже было сказано, вскоре моё волнение и восторг от возможности выпустить третье издание книги вместе с ведущим издательством были несколько **умерены (Т.п.)** осознанием того, насколько это будет сложно.* Эндрю Крейг, Как завладеть миром. Инвестируйте умно и мыслите глобально, 2019.

*Духовность идеи убита телом, а теплота тела **умерена (Т.п)** отвлеченной идеей.* Георгий Флоровский. Век патристики и эсхатология, 1939.

*Каждое поколение открывает для себя свои горизонты, заявляя об их «новизне» …однако, эти перспективы могут быть расширены, а притязания на новизну **умерены (нет Т.п.).*** Игорь Орлов, «Человек исторический» в системе гуманитарного знания, 2012.

**Прилагательное**

*Если посмотреть на долю социальных расходов в ВВП у нас, в России, то по сравнению с развитыми странами они **весьма умеренны**.* И. Осадчая. Инфляция: суть, причины, формы проявления // «Наука и жизнь», 2008.

*В то же время, по словам большинства участников рынка, налоговое бремя не является неподъемной ношей ― его размеры **вполне умеренны**.* Тимофей Бахвалов. «Бизнес-журнал», 22.01.2004.

*В старину шесть человек из десяти были богобоязненны, двое **умеренны** и двое безразличны, но и последние имели внутри себя веру.* Паисий Святогорец, Слова. Том II. Духовное пробуждение, 1999.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ ОТ 22.03.2023**

В этой теме важно использовать **орфографический словарь.** Дело в том, что среди парных прилагательных и причастий встречаются **совершенно особенные:** некоторые из них в краткой форме пишутся,  как причастия, с одной буквой Н (***заржавленный, поношенный, заплаканный***), другие же (прилагательные!) и вовсе имеют две формы письма Н и НН (***насыщенный***). Все это можно увидеть в словаре. А без словаря эти прилагательные можно определить по отсутствию **СРАВНИТЕЛЬНОЙ СТЕПЕНИ**, и вот тогда уж точно  необходим словарь.

Но у нашего прилагательного сравнительная степень есть (***умереннее***), так что оно ведет себя вполне корректно, как обычное парное причастие и прилагательное. Это видно и по орфографическому словарю.

Поэтому для определения значения по действию у причастий или качественного значения у прилагательных присутствия **проверочных признаков** (сущ.в форме Т.п., наречий степени или однородных прилагательных) **не является обязательным**, в то же время они часто присутствуют.

Comment: Мне кажется, тут дело в употреблении "аппетиты" во множественном числе.

Answer (score 1):

В роли краткого причастия, образованного от глагола "умерить" в значении "уменьшить меру чего-то", — ***"Их аппетиты (были) умерены нами"***.

В роли краткого прилагательного, образованного от существительного "умеренность" в значении "небольшой, нормальный",  — ***"Их аппетиты (были) умеренны"***.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется проблема со словом аппетиты.

Аппетиты в русском языке употреляют, разве что в переносном смысле, потому что аппетит имеет единственное число, как, например, слово настроение. Не говорят, "как ваши настроения". В переносном же смысле, "аппетиты" значат вожделения, желания чего-то. Но аппетит это уже предрасположенность что-то желать, предрасположенность к желанию, поэтому предрасположенности - не корректно. У Некрасова есть строчка с "аппетитами" в переносном смысле, но так как там стихи, то звучит, а так в классике до 1990 почти не встречается. То есть в русском это слово предикат к желанию, то, из чего потом появляется желание/желания, а "умерить аппетиты" - скорее неологическая идиома, значащая "умерить желания, смириться". Сформированные из идиом новые искусственные конструкций может звучать странно. Но в английском аппетиты, как и многие другие слова могут иметь множественную форму, отсюда семантические кальки.

***Appetites** are constantly growing* - context.reverso.net переводит как ***аппетиты** постоянно растут*.

Однако, ***Appetites** also increase with the cold weather, so we may tend to overeat when we are trying to stay warm* переводит уже как *В холодную погоду также растет **аппетит**, потому мы склонны переедать, когда пытаемся сохранить тепло.*

Я бы старался не злоупотреблять множественным числом слова аппетит без необходимости.